# Wordpress Functions Theme options formatting

Tags: php, wordpress, function, google-analytics

I have created a wordpress theme and have created a load of options for the end users to alter certain areas of the site.

I am hving issues with a text area that is to deal with the users google analytics code.

The text area works but the output of the analytics code  means it doesnt work.

In my functions.php file I have a text area for the user to entere their analytics code:

```
array (
                    'key' => 'field_52e7a858b4951',
                    'label' => __("Tracking code", 'dansiop'),
                    'name' => 'google_analytics',
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'instructions' => __("Copy and paste your Google Analytics tracking code here. You can create a free account at: http://www.google.com/analytics/", 'storini'),
                    'default_value' => '',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'maxlength' => '',
                    'formatting' => 'none',
                ),
```

No in my admin I have the text area as required:

[unable to post images due to being new on here]
http://www.dansiop.com/analytics.png

So when the user enters their specific analytics code such as this:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

The code appears on the website in the footer. It is placed in the correct place but when I view source I see the Analytics code like this:

```
&lt;script&gt;
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[&#039;GoogleAnalyticsObject&#039;]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,&#039;script&#039;,&#039;//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js&#039;,&#039;ga&#039;);

  ga(&#039;create&#039;, &#039;XX-XXXXXXXX-X&#039;, &#039;auto&#039;);
  ga(&#039;send&#039;, &#039;pageview&#039;);

&lt;/script&gt;
```

I have masked the specific ID in the analytics code for obvious reasons.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Would greatly appreciate some help and can't find anything online regarding this matter.

EDIT:
I am echoing the code in footer above /body with this:

```
<?php if( get_field('google_analytics', 'option') ) : ?><?php the_field('google_analytics', 'option'); ?><?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try to use `html_entity_decode()`

You should go to the footer and echo/print code using `html_entity_decode('Your-analytic-code-variable');`

```
<?php 
if( get_field('google_analytics', 'option') ) :
    echo html_entity_decode(get_field('google_analytics', 'option'), ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
endif 
?>
```

Comment: Hi, never used that before ad I have tried this: <?php if( get_field('google_analytics', 'option') ) : ?><?php html_entity_decode('google_analytics', 'option'); ?><?php endif ?>
 with no joy.

Comment: @DanDavies I have updated my answer you can try with that code

Comment: Hi thansk for your time and efforts but this is not working - it has improved as now the <script> and </script> appear correct but any character within th ecode are not displaying as they should - for example  ga('send', 'pageview'); is displaying as ga(&#039;send&#039;, &#039;pageview&#039;); - Any other ideas?

Comment: Ah, I missed those. I have updated my answer this will fix your issue

Comment: You legend - thanks for this. I have accepted your answer but can't vote up yet as I don't have enough reputation. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

If you print or var_dump the field, is the value already escaped or does it still holds its no-formatted value?